# iOS7 automatically sets the button to “Back” instead of previous screen’s title

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

My app is supposed to run both on iOS 7 and iOS 6 but I am seeing a bit of different behavior with iOS 7. As per my observations iOS7 automatically sets the button to “Back” instead of previous screen’s title when the title is too long. Has anyone faced the same issue. Any clue?

iOS 6 --> Back button title reads "Customer Details" and screen title is "Details"
iOS 7 --> Back button title reads "Back" and screen title is "Details"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you segue from your `FirstNavigationController` to `SecondNavigationController`. Check if the title of `UINavigationItem` of `FirstNavigationController` is not nil,

**From Documentation.**

> When the receiver is on the navigation item stack and is second from
>   the top—in other words, its view controller manages the views that the
>   user would navigate back to—the value in this property is used for the
>   back button on the top-most navigation bar. If the value of this
>   property is nil, the system uses the string “Back” as the text of the
>   back button.

Answer (score 0):

No, this does happen because (I assume) because Apple does not want the title pushed right because of long back button text. This has happened many times in my apps. You can set a custom button title if you click on the navigation bar in IB and enter text in the back button field. I would go for a shortening of the previous title, such as 'Details' in your case.